# downsizing several hundred png files from png24 to png8

Tags: image, resize, png, size, image-manipulation

I have several hundred images that I ended up saving as a large file format (png24) so I'd like to downsize them all. Is there a quick way to do this rather than manually opening each one in photoshop and saving as a png8?

Also, if I only have the png file and not the psd, can I still downsize the image from png24 to png8?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you already seem to have Photoshop, why not try the [Actions](http://blog.epicedits.com/2008/03/07/how-to-create-photoshop-actions/) feature? Very simple. If you have your files in one folder, you can apply the Action you recorded with one of them to all the rest.

Answer (score 2):

[ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/index.php) is a good tool for doing batch image conversions

Answer (score 0):

You can use [pngquant](http://pngquant.org), which supports alpha transparency and might give better color quality than Photoshop.

See [other answer how to apply pngquant to entire directories](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9647920/recursively-batch-process-files-with-pngquant).