# Recursively batch process files with pngquant

Tags: image, terminal, png, batch-processing

I have a lot of images that I would like to process with pngquant. They are organized in a pretty deep directory structure, so it is very time-consuming to manually `cd` into every directory and run `pngquant -ext .png -force 256 *.png`

Is there a way to get this command to run on every *.png in every directory within the current one, as many layers deep as necessary?

Comment: What operating system are you on?

Answer (score 77, accepted):

If you have limited depth of directories and not too many files, then lazy solution:

```
pngquant *.png */*.png */*/*.png
```

A standard solution:

```
find . -name '*.png' -exec pngquant --ext .png --force 256 {} \;
```

and multi-core version:

```
find . -name '*.png' -print0 | xargs -0 -P8 -L1 pngquant --ext .png --force 256
```

where `-P8` defines number of CPUs, and `-L1` defines a number of images to process in one pngquant call (I use `-L4` for folders with a lot of small images to save on process start).

Comment: `find . -name '*.png' -exec pngquant -ext .png -force 256 {} \;` works beautifully for me. Thank you.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, worked like a charm for me. However, could you explain the syntax regarding the number of cores? Is that a pngquant option or a OS option which divides the tasks and gives some images to each thread?

Comment: @Stewie that's `xargs`' option that tells it to run number of tasks in parallel.

Comment: Alternatively, depending on whether you have a reasonably recent `bash` or `zsh`, and the option is enabled (`shopt -s globstar` in `bash`), you can use a recursive glob:  `pngquant **/*.png`

Comment: `find . -name '*.png' -exec pngquant --ext .png --force 256 {} \;` fails with `File not found - '*.png'`

Comment: Sometimes the XARGS version doesn't work. It prints 'Bad file number'. I think problem in paths

Comment: @porneL: The multi-core version wasn't actually multi-core, as without `-L1` it adds all arguments to a single pngquant call, which processes them serially :). Fixed.

Comment: What could be a Windows equivalent of the multi-core command?

Comment: thanks for the answer, very useful indeed. The verbose flag is a nice addition to it as it can often take a while for the process to finish. The command I eventually went with on my macbook intel core i5 2.3 (I believe this has 2 cores) was: `find . -name '*.png' -print0 | xargs -0 -P2 -L4 pngquant --ext .png --force -v 256`

Comment: Mini benchmark of process start overhead (Ryzen 1700, 8c16t @ 2.7GHz), 1364 files on Win/cygwin:
`xargs -0 -L 32 -P 8 ./optipng.exe ...` - real = 19.7s || `xargs -0 -I{} -P 16 ./optipng.exe ...` - real = 22s || `xargs -0 -I{} -P 8 ./optipng.exe ...` - real = 27.7s

Answer (score 22):

With the [fish shell](http://fishshell.com/) you can run the following from the root of your project directory

```
pngquant **.png
```

Which will generate new files with extensions like `-or8.png` or `-fs8.png`.

If you want to overwrite the existing files, you can use

```
pngquant **.png --ext .png --force
```