# How To Batch Process with pngquant on Mac

Tags: macos, image, optimization, terminal, batch-processing

I'm attempting to batch process some images using pngquant and I have realized I don't really know what I'm doing. I'm on a mac and I can navigate to the executable and open it, but after that I can't access any of the functions/features of pngquant.

Basically, I've gotten to the point of ./pngquant, but don't know what to do after that. Any help from anyone?

I've got a couple hundred images to run through, so it would be nice to not have save each of them individually...

Comment: possible duplicate of [Recursively batch process files with pngquant](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9647920/recursively-batch-process-files-with-pngquant)

Comment: Similar, but most definitely NOT a duplicate. OP is asking for someone to help him understand how to use pngquant in the terminal, not necessarily how to go deep into a file directory—the question is more basic than that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If it were me, I would use [Tiny Png](http://tinypng.org) It does essentially the same thing. (I am very unfamiliar with using the terminal as well.)

Comment: This is a web service and only supports 20 at a time, I have thousands of images...

Answer (score 1):

What exactly are you trying to process?

Here is an example on usage:

```
./pngquant 256 ../test/*.png
```

I am running the command from the pngquant directory and pointing it to my test directory where I have all my png files....

Comment: I believe the OP is unfamiliar with how terminal works and is asking for a detailed "how to".

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend pngquant to osx with the help of [Homebrew](http://brew.sh/) (which you need to install first)

```
brew install pngquant
cd path/to/your/images
pngquant 256 *.png (all png-images)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Batch tool
like [a link](http://www.zarell.com/product/acc_image_batch_process/)!Acc image batch process[a panda][1]
this can dealwith png,gif,jpg and some other